# JQuery - auto advancing radios inputs "checked"

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering if anyone new how to auto advance radio inputs? basically have one radio checked, then check the next one in an interval etc.

This has been really kicking my butt. Here is what I have so far.

```
$("#image_box > :input:gt(0)").attr("checked",true);
    setInterval(function() {
        $("#image_box > :input:first")
            .next()
            .end()
            .append().attr("checked",true);
        },  3000);
```

Comment: Can you provide some HTML code ? Even better if you could make a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: i am trying to auto advance this [link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/30/fluid-css3-slideshow-with-parallax-effect/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Every second it will check the next radio.

```
var $radios = $('input[type=radio]');
$radios.each(function(i, e) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(e).prop('checked', true);
  }, 1000 * i);
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/oqubis/1/edit

Comment: +1 For understanding the question. [Here's an improvment](http://jsbin.com/oqubis/2/edit)